# "Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits" except for when I sort the RDD. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I'm running a 12-node Spark cluster on AWS EMR using m3.xlarge instances, and am trying to process 36GB of gzipped CSV data. When I run the following code, I get the error:

```
source_data = spark.read.csv('s3://my-bucket/my_csv_files/',
                             sep='\t', header=True, nullValue='\\N',
                             escape='"', schema=schema)
data = (source_data.rdd.keyBy(lambda x: x['id'])
                       .groupByKey())
```

> Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 10.4 GB of 10.4 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.

Yet when I run the same code with a sortBy it works just fine:

```
data = (source_data.rdd.keyBy(lambda x: x['id'])
                       .sortBy(lambda x: x[1]['file_timestamp'])
                       .groupByKey())
```

Why is this, and how should I troubleshoot? I'm running my cluster using `maximizeResourceAllocation`, and have tried to set `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` to a larger value without much luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587413/container-killed-by-yarn-for-exceeding-memory-limits)