# Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, google-cloud-dataproc

I am creating a cluster in google dataproc with the following characteristics:

```
Master Standard (1 master, N workers)
  Machine       n1-highmem-2 (2 vCPU, 13.0 GB memory)
  Primary disk  250 GB

Worker nodes    2
  Machine type  n1-highmem-2 (2 vCPU, 13.0 GB memory)
  Primary disk  size    250 GB
```

I am also adding in `Initialization actions` the `.sh` file from this [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/zeppelin) in order to use zeppelin.

The code that I use works fine with some data but if I use bigger amount of, I got the following error:

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 4.0 GB of 4 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

I have seen posts such as this one: [Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781354/container-killed-by-yarn-for-exceeding-memory-limits-10-4-gb-of-10-4-gb-physic) where it is recommended to change `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled` to `false`.

I am a bit confused though. Are all these configurations happening when I initialize the cluster or not?

Also where exactly is `yarn-site.xml` located? I am unable to find it in the master(cant find it in `/usr/lib/zeppelin/conf/`, `/usr/lib/spark/conf`, `/usr/lib/hadoop-yar/`) in order to change it, and if changed what do i need to 'restart'?

Comment: You can [specify properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties) in Dataproc during cluster creation: `dataproc clusters create <my-cluster> --properties yarn:yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false`

Comment: I found `yarn-site.xml` here: `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/yarn-site.xml`

After updating it you can restart YARN with command: `sudo systemctl restart hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager.service`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Igor is correct, the easiest thing to do is create a cluster and specify any additional properties to set before starting the services.

However, it's a little scary to entirely disable YARN checking that containers stay within their bounds. Either way, your VM will eventually run out of memory.

The error message is correct -- you should try bumping up `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`. It defaults to `max(384m, 0.1 * spark.executor.memory)`. On an n1-highmem-2, that ends up being 384m since `spark.executor.memory=3712m`. You can set this value when creating a cluster by using `--properties spark:spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=512m`.

If I understand correctly, the JVM and Spark try to be intelligent about keeping memory usage within `spark.executor.memory - memoryOverhead`. However, the python interpreter (where your pyspark code actually runs) is outside their accounting, and instead falls under `memoryOverhead`. If you are using a lot of memory in the python process, you will need to increase `memoryOverhead`.

Here are some resources on pyspark and Spark's memory management:

- [How does Spark running on YARN account for Python memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878846/how-does-spark-running-on-yarn-account-for-python-memory-usage)
- https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview